# Как менять Location List<Point> Location.X Location.Y?

Tags: c#

Как менять координаты моего листа из поинтов?

```
List<Point> Ellipse = new List<Point>();
```

Хочу менять координату `Ellipse[i].Y =` в разных функциях.

Comment: И чем Вам не угодил указанный в вопросе способ? Дополните вопрос, не понятна суть...

Comment: `Point` - структура или класс?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Наверняка тип `Point` у вас является структурой (значимым типом). Например, [System.Drawing.Point](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Если бы это был ссылочный тип (класс), то следующий код работал бы:

```
Ellipse[i].Y++;
```

Но значимые типы копируются по значению, поэтому при обращении к коллекции `Ellipse[i]` вы получаете *копию* структуры.

Соответственно, изменив копию, нужно записать её на прежнее место. Выглядит это примерно так:

```
var point = Ellipse[i];
point.Y++;
Ellipse[i] = point;
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!